# why doesn't Spinner respond to setOnItemSelectedListener?

Tags: android, android-spinner

The code below fills the spinner with data but when i select an item in the spinner no event is triggered. Any ideas ?

spinner itself is inside of toolbar

toolbar_spinner_item

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"/>
```

some activity onCreate

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.date_ranges, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.toolbar_spinner_item);

Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);


spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: How did you check that nothing happens?

Comment: @Onik, set debugger inside of methods

Comment: Instead of adding a `return;` try to actually add a `Log.d()` call for instance and see if it writes it actually. If you're using Android Studio, sometimes it skips certain lines when debugging.

Comment: @Darwind, i spent 3 hours of my time on this thing trying to fix bug never existed... hahah. Man answer, this and get the bounty. Thanks

Comment: Sure - there you go :-) I've been tearing my hair out sometimes, because it skips lines when debugging - not sure if Eclipse does this as well - it could be because it's a `return` and that's kinda implicit when the method returns `void` in the first place :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turning my comment into an answer ;-)

Instead of adding `return;` try to add a `Log.d` call for instance and see if it writes the log statement.

If you're using Android Studio, sometimes it skips certain lines when debugging.

Comment: Read all over the internet to find out why it doesn't work but evidently for the wrong thing. Thank you Darwind.